# Having trouble with parentheses in unix find and correct syntax

Tags: bash, find

This one liner works, the goal:

- search a directory
- find all files that are newer than a `timestamp` file
- that are NOT named .DS_Store
- otherwise, list all those other files.

I came up with this, which works, but I see examples online that use a lot of parentheses for which I am using none. I  was thinking there may be a better way:

```
find /Users/$USER/Library/Messages/Attachments -not -name ".DS_Store" -not -name "timestamp" -name "*" -type f -newer /Users/$USER/Library/Messages/scripts/timestamp
```

And ultimately I want to take the results and copy them to a specific place.  For that I was going to append this:

```
-exec cp {} archive_files/ \;
```

Comment: And what is the problem when you add `-exec...`?

Answer (score 2):

You *could* combine all the `-not` expressions into a parenthesized group by applying [de Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

```
-not \( -name .DS_Store -o -name timestamp \)
```

I don't see the point in your simple case, but if you had lots of names to exclude it might be clearer.

Comment: On the other hand, using `-regex` instead of `-name` would allow you to make it even more compact.

Comment: Quick question, if I don't want names getting overwritten on the `cp` how would I append a serial number, I can make a counter, but the value, how do I append it pre-file-extension in the find command just where the -exec cp happens?  - Thanks